# How to run powershell command in PHP

Tags: php, powershell, cryptography

I want to run powershell through PHP program. In powershell I have to run the command  "Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha256 .\SHYAM.jpeg" to generate hash value. Shyam.jpeg is a file which is located in the directory C:\wamp64\www\Dedup. Here is my code

```
<?php
$psPath = "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
$psDIR = "C:\\wamp64\\www\\Dedup";
$psScript = "SHYAM.JPEG";
$runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
$runCMD = $psPath.'Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha256./'.$psDIR.$psScript; 
$out= shell_exec($runCMD);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($out);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

But it is not working. I am struggling to make it work. When I tried "Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha256 .\SHYAM.jpeg" command in powerShell it works fine. Please help me out.

Comment: Is there really no function in php to do this without other languages? Using powershell in PHP looks a little bit scary for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The output is `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell
v1.0\powershell.exeGet-FileHash -Algorithm sha256./C:\wamp64\www\DedupSHYAM.JPEG`

Missing a backslash escape in the path to PowerShell, no spaces, wrong folder path, it's not going to work.

Try something like:

```
<?php
$psPath = "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
$fileDir = "C:\\wamp64\\www\\Dedup";
$fileName = "SHYAM.JPEG";
$runCMD = "$psPath -Command \"Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 -Path '$fileDir\\$fileName' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash\"";
$out= shell_exec($runCMD);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($out);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

I haven't tried to exec it, but that at least prints a sensible looking command.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the ./ with a space and add a space before the Get-FileHash.

```
$runCMD = $psPath.'Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha256./'.$psDIR.$psScript;
```

To

```
$runCMD = $psPath.' Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha256 '.$psDIR.$psScript;
```